# What is wrong with my code?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, functions, broken-code

What is wrong with my code below

```
f1[ar_, cj_, mj_, tj_, kj_, s_, w_] := 
ar*J[t] + cj*R[t] + mj*J[t] - tj*R[t] - kj*J[t] + s*R[t]*J[t] + w*J[t]*R[t];
g1[aj_, cr_, mr_, tr_, kr_, s_, w_] := 
aj*R[t] + cr*J[t] + mr*R[t] - tr*J[t] - kr*R[t] - s*R[t]*J[t] - w*J[t]*R[t];

splot = StreamPlot[{f[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], g[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]}, {J, -4,4},{R, -4, 4}];
Manipulate[Show[splot,ParametricPlot[Evaluate[First[{x[t], y[t]} /.
NDSolve[{J'[t] == f1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], R'[t] == g1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]]], {t, 0,T}, PlotStyle -> Red]],
{{T, 10}, 1, 100}, {{point, {1, 0}}, Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I am getting the error
`ConstantArray::ilsmn: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of ConstantArray[{J,R},-\[Infinity]].`

Comment: This is not a free debugging service...

Comment: I don't really understand the error in my code, that is why I am asking it here. I thought this was one of the purpose of the site. If you can help, or point me to the right direction, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: It would have be easy for you to find out that `Manipulate` and `ParametricPlot`. The error occurs already when executing `NDSolve[{J'[t] == f1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], R'[t] == g1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
   Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]`. You try to solve for `x` and `y` but the equations are in terms of `J` and `R`. And you defined `f1` and `g1` as functions in seven variables but you call them only with six variables. `NDSolve[{
  J'[t] == f1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  R'[t] == g1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  Thread[{J[0], R[0]} == point]
  }, {J, R}, {t, 0, T}]` seems to work.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the reply but your code is still giving errors. I don't really understand the errors

Comment: Please read the error message. Of course you have to set `point` and `T` to numeric values first. For example `point = {1, 0};T = 1;` Then it works.

Comment: @DMH16 I think the title of your post should at least attempt to describe the problem you are facing. Presently 95 % of the posts in this SE could be called what is wrong with my code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after fixing a lot of typos, the code works

```
f1[ar_, cj_, mj_, tj_, kj_, s_, w_, R_, J_] := 
  ar*J + cj*R + mj*J - tj*R - kj*J + s*R*J + w*J*R;
g1[aj_, cr_, mr_, tr_, kr_, s_, w_, R_, J_] := 
  aj*R + cr*J + mr*R - tr*J - kr*R - s*R*J - w*J*R;

splot = StreamPlot[{f1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, R, J], 
   g1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, R, J]}, {J, -4, 4}, {R, -4, 4}]
Manipulate[
 Show[splot, 
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    First[{R[t], J[t]} /. 
      NDSolve[{J'[t] == f1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, R[t], J[t]], 
        R'[t] == g1[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, R[t], J[t]], 
        Thread[{R[0], J[0]} == point]}, {R, J}, {t, 0, T}]]], {t, 0, 
    T}, PlotStyle -> Red]], {{T, 10}, 1, 100}, {{point, {1, 0}}, 
  Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: fig1]